# What is the fastest form of communication between devices?

Tags: java, communication, serial-communication, telecommunication

I have a web bot continuously scanning a web page for a certain string, and when it finds it, I want a notification to be sent to my phone. The web bot is written in Java, so what would be the best way to communicate the information? Is it SMS or perhaps Bluetooth? Thanks!

Edit: A little more information... I have an iPhone 5c and the distance between my phone and computer can be assumed to be short (as in in the same house)

Comment: Depends on where your smartphone is located. Bluetooth only works from short distances

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that I'm fine with it only notifying me when I'm at a short distance (as in I'm at my house)

Comment: If you have got some expirience in AndroidDevelopment you could create a APP and use a android notification.

Comment: @Luftbaum I have iOS, so I'm assuming that won't work

Answer (score 0):

You could have your phone constantly polling the web bot computer to see if it has any new notifications for it, or you could have your phone run a web server (assuming you are on the same network) and let the web bot contact it when it has something to share.

However, I suspect that you may find it easier to simply use one of the common mobile notification services such as:

- https://aws.amazon.com/sns/
- https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

These have the advantage of working across mobiles, should have good examples and user forum etc, and most importantly are designed to work when you mobile is not actively running an app, so will likely be much more power efficient than a home grow solution.